# How to use rules to take a user from a group content page to the group page the content belongs to?

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups

I'm using [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) (7.x-1.5) and wonder how to write a rule that would take the user from a group content page to the group page the content belongs to?

The event could be triggered by a button on the group content.

For example: I am viewing the page of the University of Berkeley and if I click on the button there, I am taken to the California universities page (University of Berkeley page is group content, California universities page is group.)

Notice I did not say "back" to the group since the user can land on the group content page without first landing on the group page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many approaches available here. You can use the rules link module to do this. It can fetch the parent node and redirect to it when the link is clicked.
https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link

However, check if organic groups provides tokens that you could use to build the link in html. Or a php snippet to grab the nid of the parent if it exists and print it as part of a link.

The other option is crumbs, the breadcrumbs module that automatically outputs the subgroup hierarchy.
https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs

If you are using panels, I'm pretty sure there's a replacement pattern for the parent if you create custom content.

Comment: Tried Rules Link but it also requires the use of a rule. Prior to using this module, I couldn't write a simple redirect rule because many of the tokens provided by Organic Group do not work. So nothing changes. Will try crumbs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! The easiest solution was with panel. Thanks. :)